# ParseQuery fails to get object that exists in backend

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, message

reposting this question since I didn't get any responses the first time around. Parse doesn't appear to have any simple means of contacting them about this (which is frustrating), so I really hope someone here can help.

I am currently using Parse to create a messaging app. I have two fundamental ParseObjects in addition to the standard ParseUser, a Chatroom and a Message. A Chatroom contains pointers to the two users in the Chatroom. A Message contains the content of the Message, a pointer to the user who posted it, and a pointer to the Chatroom.

First, I create a list of all the Chatrooms that the current user is in. Then, I'm trying to create a second list of the most recent message in all of these Chatrooms (I have made it impossible to make a Chatroom without sending at least one Message first).

My code looks like this:

```
TextView mostRecent = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.mostRecent);

Date dt1 = null;
ParseQuery lastMessage = ParseQuery.getQuery("Message");
ParseObject chatroom = (ParseObject) roomList.get(position);
Log.w("Chatroom ObjectID...", room.getObjectId());

try {
    lastMessage.whereEqualTo("chatroom", chatroom.fetchIfNeeded());
    List<ParseObject> allMessages = lastMessage.find();

    Log.w("# of Messages...", "Size of the list: " + allMessages.size() + ", Count of query: " + allMessages.count());

    if (allMessages.size() > 0) {
        mostRecent.setText((String) theList.get(theList.size() - 1).get("content"));
        dt1 = allMessages.get(allMessages.size() - 1).getCreatedAt();
    }

} catch (ParseException err) {

    err.printStackTrace();

    Log.w("PARSE ERROR", err.getMessage());

}
```

This code works for every Chatroom where the current user is the one who created the Chatroom and the Message in that Chatroom. However, whenever I have a different user attempt to start a Chatroom and send a Message to the original user, the code fails.

To be clear, the second user successfully creates both a Chatroom and a Message. I've verified that the Chatroom gets successfully added to the original user's list of Chatrooms, and that the Message contains a pointer to the correct Chatroom. However, for whatever reason, the Logs reveal a list size of 0 and a count of 0. I've even tried querying for the second user's exact message on the original user's account, and it claims the thing doesn't exist.

Any ideas? Could this have something to do with ACL? Thanks in advance!

NOTE: I've confirmed that both users are correctly included in the Message's ACL. What gives? Why isn't this working?

Comment: have you tried findInBackground instead of find? At the point where you print the log, it could be that the your object is not fechted yet. Thats why there is findInBackground with a callback.

Comment: do a query for the specific class/objectId you think your user should be able to read.. on NONE parse returns an error as JSON.  whats in it?

Comment: "no results found for query"

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the query to fetch the data.

```
lastMessage.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
     public void done(List<ParseObject> allMessages, ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) {
            Log.w("# of Messages...", "Size of the list: " + allMessages.size() + ", Count of query: " + allMessages.count());

         } else {
            Log.w("Exception thrown", e.getMessage());
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I just attempted this, but still no luck - the logs still say that the size of the list is 0. I have, however, discovered that messaging works fine between Android users - however, when an iPhone user sends a message, that's where things go awry. I'm going to check with my iOS developer to see what the issue might be.

Comment: could you also check if chatroom is fetched correctly? Maybe its also not there, yet. (...whereEqualTo("chatroom", chatroom.fetchIfNeeded());)